# radio signal range with wireless connection

Tags: windows-7

My friend living in the 4th floor have a NetFasteR IAD 2 wireless router and he gave me the security key. But the problem is when i am in his room with my laptop the connection works very good....but when I return back to my room down 1st floor, there is no connection even though sometimes the bars shows me 4 bars...but no connection at all. What is the problem and what shall I do?

Comment: Wireless is two way, the router may have a strong signal that can reach you on the first floor, but your wireless card does not have a strong enough signal to reach the router on the 4th floor. Not sure what you can do with a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors here.  Can the router accept a higher gain antenna?  Many use a standard connector and a number of companies make higher gain antennas.  D-Link makes several that are not that expensive.

Some Cardbus wireless cards can connect to an external antenna as well.  They need a special connector and not sure how common but I use one all the time for a Symantec gateway device.